# Delete rows from both tables where id equals from both tables

Tags: mysql

I have to tables `A` and `B`. A table contains `MUL` key from B table.

```
A (table)
ID  auto-increment
Avar mul-key             <- B table value
```

```
B (table)
ID   auto-increment
Bvar varchar(64) mul-key
```

How can I delete rows from A table where `Avar` has the same values as B table `ID`?

So far I have this:

```
DELETE A, B
FROM A, B
WHERE A.Avar = B.ID;
```

Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE A, B
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.Avar = B.ID
```

Comment: This deletes from A table, but I need to delete from B table aswell, or am I wrong? I updated title.

Comment: You asked: *How can I delete rows from A*. But if you want to delete from both tables then just add it: `DELETE A, B FROM A JOIN ...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast avar as it has different data type. You can do something like below :

```
DELETE A,B
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON CAST(A.Avar) = B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete matching rows from both tables:

```
DELETE A, B
FROM A INNER JOIN B 
ON A.Avar = B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
DELETE FROM A 
WHERE b.id NOT IN 
       (SELECT id 
        FROM B 
        WHERE id is NOT NULL/*This line is unlikely to be needed 
                               but using NOT IN...*/
      )
```